# Groovy not compiling in IntelliJ

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, spock

I'm setting up Groovy tests and none of the Groovy classes (Spock and regular classes) are being compiled. In other words, no .class in target/

Details and conditions:

This is a maven project.

- I have this working natively in Mac IntelliJ. I am seeing the error in an Ubuntu VM.
- Mac version (working) is IJ v.13, Ubuntu version (broken) is IJ v.14.
- Groovy plugin is enabled, and Spock plugin is installed and enabled.
- I tried everything in [Groovy file does not compile in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310563/groovy-file-does-not-compile-in-intellij-idea), with no luck.
- Nothing in the IntelliJ docs or google searches I could thank of helps.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there an error message, or is it not even trying to compile?

Comment: I'd report this to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newissue providing some information on what you see, a screenshot of your Compiler settings, and your log (Help | Show log)